# Port Matlab code involving matplotlib setting axes position in pixels

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, position, axes

I would need to port this code from matlab to python:

```matlab
fig;
stringNumber = '0.1'
set(gca,'units','pixels','position',[1 1 145 55],'visible','on')
box('on')
```

The above code results in the following figure [matlabTest1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5m2YC.png) (screen maximized).

Note that the axes don't scale if the figure is resized, see [matlabTest2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwicv.png)

I've tried porting it in python converting the position and offset from transFigure to Display / Pixel.

Here's my code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
inv = fig.transFigure.inverted()
offset = inv.transform((1, 1))
position = inv.transform((145, 55))
ax.set_position([offset[0], offset[1], position[0],position[1]])
plt.show()
```

My code results in [pythonTest1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qufPC.png) (screen maximized). The box size looks different from [matlabTest1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5m2YC.png).

Also if I resize the figure, the box changes in size, see [pythonTest2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzPtK.png)

How can I obtain the exact same result as the matlab code?

Thanks to anyone that can help with this.

Comment: Try to make a minimal example with just one thing you ask for. Also show the desired result and how the matplotlib result differs.

Comment: @roadrunner66 thank you for your comment. I edited my question and added some images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matplotlib figures are positionned in figure coordinates by default. Hence there is no direct equivalent to the matlab code provided.

One way of specifying the position of the axes in pixels would be to use a `AnchoredSizeLocator` from `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator`.

```
import matplotlib.transforms as mtrans
import mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator as ins
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

axes_locator = ins.AnchoredSizeLocator([1, 1, 145, 55],
                                       "100%", "100%",
                                       loc="center",
                                       bbox_transform=mtrans.IdentityTransform(),
                                       borderpad=0)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_axes_locator(axes_locator)

plt.show()
```